# questions re migration antlr3 to antlr4 (apache pig) (3)

Tags: antlr4

question about Apache Pig antlr3/antlr4 migration.

Original parser is QueryParser.g [here](https://github.com/apache/pig/tree/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/parser)

Question: do we still use bang (!) to indicate "dont include in AST" ?? ( am guessing no but want to check)

thnx v much for your time on this, mr

```
 217 
 218 // STATEMENTS
 219 
 220 statement : SEMI_COLON!
 221           | general_statement SEMI_COLON!
 222           | split_clause SEMI_COLON!
 223           | inline_clause SEMI_COLON!
 224           | import_clause SEMI_COLON!
 225           | realias_clause SEMI_COLON!
 226           | register_clause SEMI_COLON!
 227           | assert_clause SEMI_COLON!
 228           // semicolons after foreach_complex_statement are optional for backwards compatibility, but to keep
 229           // the grammar unambiguous if there is one then we'll parse it as a single, standalone semicolon
 230           // (which matches the first statement rule)
 231           | foreach_statement
 232 ;
 233
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove all tree rewrite operators.

The following v3 snippet:

```
inline_rewite_operators
 : rule1 TOKEN1^ rule2 TOKEN2!
 ;

rewite_operator
 : rule3 TOKEN1 rule4 -> ^(TOKEN1 rule3 rule4)
 ;
```

should be rewritten for v4 as:

```
inline_rewite_operators
 : rule1 TOKEN1 rule2 TOKEN2
 ;

rewite_operator
 : rule3 TOKEN1 rule4
 ;
```